# Finding Sendgrid unique opens with Laravel

Tags: laravel, sendgrid

I am using SendGrid SMTP to send mail through my site.  I am also using the SendGrid event webhook to record all of the opens/clicks/bounces.

SendGrid tracks unique opens on their internal dashboard and I would like to show my users the same info.

**Schema**

```
------------------------------------------
userId | emailId | msg_email      | event|
------------------------------------------
   1   |  27898  | test@test.com  | open |
```

Basically, I need to find all records with:

1. Event == "open"
2. where userId == $userId
3. count distinct msg_email for each emailId.

I am completely stuck, but I think the way to approach this is to run a query that grabs all emails for the userId and with event == "open". Group them by emailId.

```
$query = EmailStats::where('userId', '=', $userId)
                    ->where('event', '=', 'open')
                    ->groupBy('emailId')
                    ->get();
```

Then loop through each group and grab the count of distinct email addresses.

I cannot figure out how to loop through each "group" to find the distinct email address.

Is there another approach that I should be considering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel has a Collection method "Unique" that does this.  Pretty easy after I found it:

```
$query = EmailStats::where('userId', '=', $userId)
                    ->where('event', '=', 'open')
                    ->groupBy('emailId')
                    ->get();


    $unique = $query->unique(function ($item) {
        return $item['emailId'].$item['msg_email'];
    });
```